# multiplying int with values from char array not working

Tags: java, arrays

i am having a problem with multipling a simple int value (1) with the values from a char-array:

```
public void doStuff(String values)
{
    char[] numbers = values.toCharArray();
    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(numbers[i] + " " + result);
        result *= numbers[i];
    }

    // more stuff here
}
```

in my case the input string-parameter is "73167". in the line "result *= numbers[i]" result should be 7 after the first iteration, but debug info in eclipse says that result = 55.
any hints??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that `"73167"` isn't a number. It's a string made of the characters `"7"`, `"3"`, `"1"`, `"6"`, `"7"`. `char` in Java are Unicode code points, and `'7'` is 55 in ASCII/UTF-8. You want to do

```
result *= Character.getNumericValue(numbers[i]);
```

Doc for: [Character.getNumericValue(char)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char))

Answer (score 2):

the char values are ascii, a '1' is not 1

to get real numbers, use (charValue - '0')